# Element selection and click count on an external component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a react project. I am using an external component (Scroller.jsx) which I can't modify.

```
<Scroller />
```

When I inspect the component part in browser, I see the following.

```
<div>
    <!-- many other tags and divs -->

    <button type="button" class="container custom-left" data-unique-id="show-left">
        <div>...</div>
    </button>

    <button type="button" class="container custom-right" data-unique-id="show-right">
        <div>...</div>
    </button>
    <!-- many other tags and divs -->
</div>
```

Is there a way I could target these 2 buttons using the `data-unique-id` property

and be able to keep a counter on it each time the button is clicked?

Those buttons already come with some click functionality. I don't want to affect that in any way.

Just looking to keep a count on clicks and I can't modify the component.

Note that I am trying to achieve this by targeting the buttons in someway and keep a count.

I can't modify the button and add onClick on it by changing things in the Scroller component.

Attempted the following but query selection is coming up undefined.

Plus this is a React project.

Trying not to have to use document.querySelector and instead go for something React specific.

Selection itself is currently coming up undefined which is an issue.

```
const = leftButton = document.querySelector('[data-unique-id="show-left"]');
const = rightButton = document.querySelector('[data-unique-id="show-right"]');
```

After being able to select, hoping to count via following which is untested. Unsure if it will work.

And again, this is a React project. Hoping to write it with something more React specific.

```
leftButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setCount(count - 1);
});

rightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setCount(count + 1);
});
```

Query is essentially why my selection is not working.
And how I could keep a count on when these buttons are clicked in a React fashion. Thanks.

MyComponent.jsx

```
import Scroller from 'external-lib/Scroller';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const leftButton = document.querySelector('[data-unique-id="show-left"]'); // undefined
        const rightButton = document.querySelector('[data-unique-id="show-right"]'); // undefined

        leftButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            setCount(count - 1);
        });

        rightButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            setCount(count + 1);
        });
    }, []);

    return (<Scroller/>);
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: As an aside, I'm surprised that `const = leftButton = document...` is compiling - I believe the correct syntax is `const leftButton = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Class version may look something like this. May be a bit verbose/outdated but could point you in the right direction.

```
    import Scroller from 'external-lib/Scroller';
    import React from 'react'
    
    export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
          super(props)
        this.state = {
          count: 0,
          setCount: 0
      }
      this.handleLeft=this.handleLeft.bind(this)
      this.handleRight=this.handleRight.bind(this)
    }
    
      handleLeft(){
        this.setState({count: count - 1 })
    }
    
      handleRight(){
        this.setState({count: count -1})
    }
    
    render(){
      const [count, setCount] = this.state
      return(
        <div>
          <!-- many other tags and divs -->
    
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleLeft} class="container custom-left" data-unique- 
     id="show-left">
              <div>...</div>
          </button>
    
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRight} class="container custom-right" data- 
     unique-id="show-right">
              <div>...</div>
          </button>
      <Scroller/>
          <!-- many other tags and divs -->
      </div>
   
     )}
    }
```

Comment: Hooks don't work inside of [Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#but-what-is-a-hook). In the way that React is written nowadays, we have migrated from Class Components to [Functional Components w/ Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: Pls have a look at the question. I've mentioned I can't modify Scroller component. Looking for a solution from the point where I am using it.